# MS Access count-distinct w/o subqueries or group bys

Tags: mysql, ms-access, logic

Every solution I've seen thus far includes using sub-queries or group-by's which definitely work.

There's an even easier solution that being: `count(distinct X) from table_x` which unfortunately doesn't work in MS Access.

Without using sub-queries or group-by's, have you managed to count the number of distinct items in a column of a table?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do that in access without subquery

Answer (score 0):

You can open a recordset with DAO with the table sorted on all relevant fields.

Then read the recordset from start to end counting one up whenever a record is different from the previously read record.

Not very useful, but you asked.